# Android: How to copy files to asset folder during build

Tags: android

I am developing a cross-platform project(iOS and Android).

I have a /resource folder that contain some .png files.

I know that only the files that in /asset folder are compiled into the .apk file.

Now I need copy the files from /resource to /asset folder manually.

It is too inconvenient.

Is is possible to copy files in /resource to /asset during build project automatically?
(p.s. I am using Eclipse for development.)

Comment: i think  you need to alter the ANT used or create an ANT script for your own, or simple create a batch file .bat that copies all files  from folder x to folder y, run the batch, then export your app to apk

Comment: Or more generally, you want to set up a "pre build step" for whatever build system you are using.